# Not able to exclude javax.persistence from javaee-api maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am trying to exclude javax.persistence from javaee-api maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But even after adding the exclusion I still have the javax.persistence package in the `javaee-api-7.0.jar`

Answer (score 0):

A dependency exclusion excludes a jar from the resolution of the artifact.
It means that the dependency (`jar`) will not be transitively pulled during the build.
In your case, it means this dependency:

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
```

will not be included in the resolution of the dependency :

```
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<version>7.0</version>
```

and so will not be included in the artifact that you build.

But it doesn't mean that classes with a package that starts with `javax.persistence` will be removed from the jar.
The `javax:javaee-api:7.0` jar will be indeed be provided with its original content.

---

Besides, your exclusion makes no sense.
`org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence` is not a dependency provided by `javax:javaee-api`.

`javax:javaee-api` is the Java EE API while `org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence` refers to a repackaging of the specific `javax.persistence` API of java EE + some extensions provided by EclipseLink.